# how to sort data by geohash in firestore v9 and how does querying geohash work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How do I sort data by geohash in firestore v9? V8 docs give this example:

```
const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
const promises = [];
for (const b of bounds) {
  const q = db.collection('cities')
    .orderBy('geohash')
    .startAt(b[0])
    .endAt(b[1]);

  promises.push(q.get());
}

// Collect all the query results together into a single list
Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
  const matchingDocs = [];

  for (const snap of snapshots) {
    for (const doc of snap.docs) {
      const lat = doc.get('lat');
      const lng = doc.get('lng');

      // We have to filter out a few false positives due to GeoHash
      // accuracy, but most will match
      const distanceInKm = geofire.distanceBetween([lat, lng], center);
      const distanceInM = distanceInKm * 1000;
      if (distanceInM <= radiusInM) {
        matchingDocs.push(doc);
      }
    }
  }

  return matchingDocs;
```

I do not know how to translate it to V9, I have tried like so:

```
    const { latitude, longitude } = location?.coords || {};
    if (latitude && longitude) {
      const radiusInM = 50 * 100000;
      const center = [latitude, longitude];
      const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
     
      for (const b of bounds) {
        const q = query(
          collection(firestore, "laboratories"),
          orderBy("geoHash"),
          startAt(b[0]),
          endAt(b[1])
        );
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
      }
    }
```

But it does not return any results, how does those queries work, because in the bounds results when I set radius to 50 * 100 I get 4 arrays with hashes, I assume those are points on a map

```
0: (2) ['u3j', 'u3k']
1: (2) ['u3n', 'u3p']
2: (2) ['u3m', 'u3n']
3: (2) ['u3q', 'u3r']
```

however when I increase the search radius to 50 * 100000 I get only

```
0: (2) ['h', '~']
```

I do not understand where do I make mistake, one of those locations is intentionally very close to where I am. And assuming this search was successful, would it return just locations in area or would those be sorted? Perhaps should I use some additional library to for that? Would you recommend one, please? And should I store latitude and longitude together with geohashes or this would be enough?

Comment: Your translation to the v9 syntax looks fine, but you have a typo in the field name here: `orderBy("geoHash"),` That should be `orderBy("geohash"),` with a lowercase `h` in `hash`.

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for reply, so geohash is a data type? I thought that would look for a field by that name. I basically store location as geohash - string in a field geoHash in every document in the collection, I want to retrieve all documents sorted by distance from me, so what would be the steps to take? The bigger radius I set the weirder the bounds get, above 250 km there is one arr with singe char, so I assume it is not ment to search that far or should iI retrieve them once, store in state and then try to sort by location some way? Thanks

Comment: The `geohash` field is a string value, not a specific data type. O recommend reading  up on geohashes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) or watching my video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).  --- But the problem in your code here is that you mistyped the field **name** in your second/v9 query, as you spelled `geoHash` different than in the first/v8 query.  Even if you remove the `startAt`/`endAt` clauses you'll get no results, since no document has a field with that misspelled name.

Comment: Hi @Seven, did you make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Posting Frank's comments for visibility.

Your translation to the v9 syntax looks fine, but you have a typo in the field name here: `orderBy("geoHash")`, should be replaced with `orderBy("geohash")`, with a lowercase `h` in `hash`.

The `geohash` field is a string value, not a specific data type. You may want to check the [article about geohashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) or [watch a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q) about it.

To reiterate, the issue in your code here is that you mistyped the field name in your second/v9 query, as you spelled `geoHash` differently than in the first/v8 query. Even if you remove the `startAt`/`endAt` clauses, you'll get no results, as no document has a field with that misspelled name.